# ban single IP with iptables for web app on docker

Tags: docker

I have a web app that runs on docker. There is a nginx & django container in my VPS. I want to test how I can block access from a single IP using `iptables` command.

According to the documentation, I need to add rules to the DOCKER-USER chain.
https://docs.docker.com/network/iptables/

however, even after I add my own IP address to the ban list

```
iptables -A DOCKER-USER -s XXX.XXX.XX.XXX -j DROP
```

I am still able to access my web app when I enter the URL in my browser.

Comment: it's not clear whether you run the command on the host or inside the container